# HttpClient Timeout doesn't work occasionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

my problem is that my `HttpClient` timeout is 100 ms, so  if my request passes 100 milliseconds, I will stop request. Usually when request passed 100 ms I can catch `TimeoutException` so I can stop request

But occasionally request passing 500 , 800 ,2000 ms but I can not catch `TimeoutException` or another exception.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}/", ApiHelper._systemInfo.WebApiAddress));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    StringContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    long time = 0;
    try
    {
        swCheck.Restart();
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/Access/CheckPlate", content).Result;
        swCheck.Stop();
        time = swCheck.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = new PlateCheckApiResponseModel();
            string respData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlateCheckApiResponseModel>(respData);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Warn("response.IsSuccessStatusCode :" + response.StatusCode);
            _logger.Info("Request Message : " + response.RequestMessage);
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        swCheck.Stop();
        time = swCheck.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        _logger.Warn("Checkapi timeout ,response time: " + time);
    }
    catch (AggregateException)
    {
        swCheck.Stop();
        time = swCheck.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        _logger.Warn("Checkapi timeout ,response time: " + time);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "Exception");
        throw ex;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That is not much time for an http request. Could be DNS resolution as described in the remarks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: It could also be that you are occassionally deadlocking. [You should **never** use `.Result` on an async call in an asp.net context.](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). If you you cannot convert your code to async "all the way down" then use `HttpWebRequest` instead of `HttpClient`.

Comment: Well , Does this cause the asp.net web api to crash?

Comment: Depends on your definition of crash. If it is deadlocking the call will just hang. I don't know if that is your problem, but I do know you should not block on async calls. And that is not an opinion, that is a fact. I [created a sample web api](https://github.com/crowcoder/DeadLock.git) that demonstrates a deadlock so you can clone it and see what happens when you make a GET request to the Home controller.

Comment: Thank you very much for sample api. How can I use HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient .Also I must wait for response

Comment: [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.113).aspx) is a little more work, but it does not force you to make async calls. It will block until it returns but it is a synchronous block so it will not cause any deadlocks.

Comment: Okay I will change it. Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) says that:

> A Domain Name System (DNS) query may take up to 15 seconds to return or time out. If your request contains a host name that requires resolution and you set Timeout to a value less than 15 seconds, it may take 15 seconds or more before a WebException is thrown to indicate a timeout on your request.

If your `ApiHelper._systemInfo.WebApiAddress` contains domain name, this could be a reason.

Comment: ApiHelper._systemInfo.WebApiAddress my Mvc Web Api Adress as 192.168.2.192:8885